# Cassandra delete time much slower than insert. Why?

Tags: python, data-structures, cassandra, datamodel, cql3

I know that issuing tons of deletes on the same Cassandra row is an anti pattern because of the time it takes to make reads ([read here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets)). But I'm also seeing that making deletes takes an order of magnitude more time.

Consider this python script which adds several values to the same row, then adds them again, then deletes them one at a time, then adds them again. For each activity the time is monitored and displayed on screen.

```
import cql
from time import time

connection = cql.connect('localhost',cql_version='3.0.0', keyspace='rkg')
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE test")
except:
    pass

cqlStatement = """
    CREATE TABLE test (
        a int,
        b text,
        c text,
        d text,
        PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
    );
"""
cursor.execute(cqlStatement)

n = 1000

insertStatement = """
    INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d)
    VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}');
"""

deleteStatement = """
    DELETE FROM test
    WHERE a = {0} AND b = '{1}' AND c = '{2}';
"""

t = time()
for i in xrange(0,n):
    cursor.execute(insertStatement.format(1,i,i,i))
print "initial insert time:\t"+ str(time() - t)

t = time()
for i in xrange(0,n):
    cursor.execute(insertStatement.format(1,i,i,i))
print "second insert time:\t"+ str(time() - t)

t = time()
for i in xrange(0,n):
    cursor.execute(deleteStatement.format(1,i,i))
print "delete time:\t"+ str(time() - t)

t = time()
for i in xrange(0,n):
    cursor.execute(insertStatement.format(1,i,i,i))
print "next insert time:\t"+ str(time() - t)
```

The output to this script looks like this:

```
$ python insertDeleteTest.py 
    initial insert time:    0.369267940521
    second insert time:     0.368498086929
    delete time:           10.8632941246
    next insert time:       0.313306808472
```

Can someone tell me *why* column deletes are taking such a long time as compared to inserts?

My mental model is that an insert or a delete are basically the same thing: a disembodied column that gets written to the end of the commitlog and shoved in the memtable. In the case of the insert, it contains a new value for that column, in the case of a delete, it contains a tombstone for that column. Where does my mental model go wrong?

Comment: I wonder if inserts are very optimistic or heavily weighted for eventually consistentcy while deletes are going to block until deletes occur everywhere?

Comment: try setting `tracing on` so that you can break down the delete time which will give more info about the "bottleneck"

Comment: I would expect the data path to take the same length of time: as you say, a delete is just an insert.  Maybe the parsing for delete is slower: is it the same using prepared statements?